# jQuery Waypoints doesn't trigger on UIWebView

Tags: jquery, uiwebview

I'm working on a mobile web app and have a problem with the [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about) in the UIWebView. It works perfectly if the user scrolls down smoothly but as soon as the bounce effect is too large the waypoint does not trigger.

```
$listfooter = $('#listfooter');
opts = {
  offset: function () {
    return $(window).height() * 5;
  }
};
$listfooter.waypoint(function(event, direction)
{
  console.log('foobar');
}, opts);

<body>
 <div class="header">
  <span>Title</span>
 </div>
 <div id="container">
   <div id="listview">
    ....
   </div>
   <div id="listfooter">
     <div id="spinner"></div>
   </div><!-- /listfooter -->
 </div>
</body>

#listfooter {
  float:left;
  height:34px;
  width:100%;
}
```